# Spring bean of type java.util.Properties from properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

One of the libraries I have to use requires the `java.util.Properties` type object as a parameter. I would like to acquire the values from properties file in Spring.

Therefore, my question is - what is the best way, in Spring, to get such object as a bean using only "Java Config" (XML-less)?

Comment: Use [`PropertiesFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
class B1 {
    B1(Properties props) {
        //s
    }
}

@Configuration
class Config {

    @Bean
    B1 b1() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        // load...
        return new B1(props);
    }

...
```